# Adding Line Breaks when using nbconvert for Jupyter

Tags: markdown, jupyter

When using Jupyter Notebook, I usually am able to add 2 lines between paragraphs, and when compiling the Markdown, the 2 paragraphs are separated well with line breaks.

However, when I convert to PDF using

```
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf notebook.ipynb
```

The line breaks and paragraphing do not get translated over.

Is there a way to show that?

Answer (score 1):

I have found that adding a double space after your line will do the trick. 
For Example: 
First Line  [2 spaces] 
Second Line. [2 spaces]