# How to create accurate line breaks using nbconvert in Jupyter notebook markdown cell to create pdfs

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

Thanks for checking my question. I am struggling to use nbconvert to generate the correct layout with accurate line breaks.

Let's say I have the below texts in a Jupyter notebook markdown cell:

B) How far do you agree or disagree with the following statements? (Strongly Disagree to Strongly Agree, 1 to 5)
\n
B1. The software used in this course are easy to learn and we got familiar with them fast
\n
B2. We have enough technical support to adapt to the usage of the software
\n

I would use nbformat.v4.new_markdown_cell, nbformat.write to create multiple notebook, edit the content, then use

`!jupyter nbconvert --to pdf --no-input --PDFExporter.latex_count=1 --PDFExporter.dpi=500 \"\"\" + sheet_name + \"\"\".ipynb`

to create pdf report.

However, the result will be something like this:

```
B) How far do you agree or disagree with the following statements? (Strongly Disagree to Strongly Agree, 1 to 5)    B1. The software used in this course are easy to learn and we got familiar with them fast    B2. We have enough technical support to adapt to the usage of the software
```

Therefore the final layout of the page is not desirable. Because there will be multiple pdfs, it is not favourable to edit them one by one. By any chance, there is a solution to create the below format?

```
B) How far do you agree or disagree with the following statements? (Strongly Disagree to Strongly Agree, 1 to 5)
    B1. The software used in this course are easy to learn and we got familiar with them fast<br>\n
    B2. We have enough technical support to adapt to the usage of the software
```

Comment: Are you adding spaces after your lines in the input, like says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61195923/8508004)?  If so, maybe that specific exporter you are using isn't the best for this? (Or maybe advice [here](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/538) or [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/6484) helps?)

Comment: Adding spaces helps (but I wonder how to italics/bold the text after that. It won't function properly no matter what I am using, [**  ] or [*  *]